# Jersey on embedded Jetty with hk2 locator not loading ResourceConfig

Tags: jersey, jetty, embedded-jetty, hk2

I am using Jetty as an embedded server for Jersey.

```java
ServletHolder jerseyServletHolder = new ServletHolder(ServletContainer.class);
jerseyServletHolder.setInitOrder(1);
jerseyServletHolder.setInitParameter(
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerProperties.PROVIDER_PACKAGES,
    "com.my.package");
webAppContext.addServlet(jerseyServletHolder, "/rest/*");
```

I have a ResourceConfig implementation:

```java
@ApplicationPath("/rest")
public class MyResourceConfig extends ResourceConfig {


    static{
        System.out.println("ResourceConfig loaded");
        // this never gets calls
    }


    @Inject
    public MyResourceConfig(ServiceLocator serviceLocator, Properties serverProps) {
        packages("com.my.package");
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I launch, the MyResourceConfig class is never loaded.

If I add:

```java
jerseyServletHolder.setInitParameter(
    ServletProperties.JAXRS_APPLICATION_CLASS,
    MyResourceConfig.class.getName());
```

then the ResourceConfig does get loaded.

Why isn't MyResoureConfig getting picked up based on the @ApplicationPath annotation?

Comment: annotation scanning is a feature of `jetty-annotations`, do you have that setup in your embedded jetty?

Comment: also, `@ApplicationPath` is not a path that jetty will scan automatically, unless its specified in a `ServletContainerInitializer`'s `@HandlesType`.  Does Jersey have such a SCI?

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/master/containers/jersey-servlet/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/servlet/init/JerseyServletContainerInitializer.java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need annotation / bytecode scanning enabled.

Start by putting [`jetty-annotations-<version>.jar`](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.eclipse.jetty%22%20AND%20a%3A%22jetty-annotations%22) (and transitive dependencies) into your project.

Then, in your code, after you create your `org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server` object, do this.

```java
Server server = new Server(8080);

// Enable parsing of jndi-related parts of web.xml and jetty-env.xml
Configuration.ClassList classlist = Configuration.ClassList
        .setServerDefault(server);
classlist.addAfter("org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.FragmentConfiguration",
        "org.eclipse.jetty.plus.webapp.EnvConfiguration",
        "org.eclipse.jetty.plus.webapp.PlusConfiguration");
// Enable annotation/bytecode scanning and ServletContainerInitializer usages
classlist.addBefore(
        "org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.JettyWebXmlConfiguration",
        "org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration");

WebAppContext webAppContext = createWebAppContext();
// ....
server.start();
```

That will enable the configurations needed to perform bytecode scanning and annotation scanning, along with enabling the ability to load any `javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer` found within your webapp, including the critical one from Jersey ([`org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.init.JerseyServletContainerInitializer`](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/master/containers/jersey-servlet/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/servlet/init/JerseyServletContainerInitializer.java))